CoreMotion: attitude (roll/pitch/yaw) returning very inaccurate values
I want to add a "bubble horizon" to a camera application to help the user keep their iPhone level.
For this, I'm using the CoreMotion Attitude functionality of CMMotionManager.
However, the output I'm getting is very inaccurate.
I'm comparing my readings with Apple's own Measure app which is dead accurate, so the sensors are working fine. My own readings seem to be several degrees off.
I'm using quaternion transformation to calculate Roll (don't need Pitch/Yaw for this use case) to avoid gimbal lock, but am I perhaps missing some calibration step or something?

- (void)initializeMotionManager { 
  if (self.motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable) { 
    self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1; // Update interval in seconds
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]; 

    [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical toQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) { 
      // error handling removed for readability
      [self processDeviceMotion:motion];
    }];

  }
}

- (void)processDeviceMotion:(CMDeviceMotion *)motion {

    // use quaternions to avoid Gimbal Lock
    CMQuaternion quat = motion.attitude.quaternion;

    // calculate roll in degrees
    double roll = atan2( 2 * ( quat.w * quat.x + quat.y * quat.z ), 1 -  2 * ( quat.x * quat.x + quat.y * quat.y ) );
    roll = radiansToDegrees( roll );

    NSLog( @"Roll: %f", roll ); // readings tend to be +/- 3 degrees
}

